# react-meta-tags adds <style> in <head>

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags

I'm using react-meta-tags to add/update the meta tags in my react site. While it works fine, I noticed that there are plenty of  tags added in, which has the styles present in my css files. These  tags were not present when I was not using react-meta-tags.

Now, is it okay for these  tags to be present in ? How will it affect my site if I leave it as it is? Should I leave it as it is? I would appreciate it if you could give me a detailed explanation, since I'm new to SEO (and web-development) and have a very shallow understanding of it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its necessary for these tags to be present. What happens is that you don't ship your actual code to production, you minimize it and then bundle it for that. Since you are using react , the browser cant support `JSX` on its own so react automatically bundles you code in (runtime as well although not as efficient as in production) and converts `JSX` to different `HTML, CSS and JS` files(in minimized form) to ensure you site works fast and reliably without any support issue from different browser.So don't worry about that. While it does enable faster reloading and better performance in general which helps with google rankings but SEO is a different game altogether, you need Server Side Rendering for that and assuming you are using `create-react-app` you are using with Client Side Rendering. My suggestion don't focus on SEO and just ensure you are using Sematic elements that would be enough for now.